# Getting multiple members of an array with max values of an attribute

Tags: php, arrays, max

This is my problem:
I need to get four members of an array that have the maximum values of an attribute. I have seen the max() function already, but that one only gets me one member, and I need four. For example, I can have an array like this:

```
array( 
    array(
        "1", 
        "10"
    ), 
    array(
        "9", 
        "10"
    ), 
    array(
        "3", 
        "10"
    ), 
    array(
        "4", 
        "10"
    ), 
    array(
        "10", 
        "10"
    ), 
    array(
        "8", 
        "10"
    ), 
    array(
        "7", 
        "10"
    ), 
    array(
        "6", 
        "10"
    ), 
    array(
        "5", 
        "10"
    ), 
    array(
        "9", 
        "10"
    ) 
)
```

I need a function that will get me these four members:

> array("10", "10"), array("9", "10"), array("8", "10"), array("7",
>   "10")

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is the second attribute of each array used in the comparison?

Comment: You have two `array("9", "10")` elements. Are you wanting unique values only, or was this just an oversight?

Comment: In my code, I have more than two elements per array, but only the first element is relevant for comparison and that one is unique for each array.

Comment: Have you considered sorting the array and then splicing it to get the values you need? You can also provide your own comparison function to usort to sort by the element you want.

Comment: I could do that I guess, but that would take more time and I wanted to ask if there was such a function that would do it at once, like max() but for multiple results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the array via [usort()](http://docs.php.net/usort) in descending order.
Pick the first four items via [array_slice](http://docs.php.net/array_slice)

```
<?php
$ar = getData();
usort( $ar, function($a,$b) { return -strnatcmp($a[0], $b[0]); });
$result = array_slice($ar, 0, 4);
var_dump($result);

function getData() {
    return array(
        array("1", "10"),
        array("9", "10"),
        array("3", "10"),
        array("4", "10"),
        array("10", "10"),
        array("8", "10"),
        array("7", "10"),
        array("6", "10"),
        array("5", "10"),
    );
}
```

prints

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "10"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "10"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "9"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "10"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "8"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "10"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "7"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "10"
  }
}
```

Comment: I will try it, but since I have a few more changes I have to make I wouldn't be able to see if it works right now. When I do, I'll get back to you. Thanks in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use a simple algorithm (the simplest that exists I think), quickly :

```
$nbrItems = 0;
$greaters = array();
$lessthan = null;
while ($nbrItems < 4 && count($myArray) >= 4) {
    $tmp = reset($myArray);
    foreach($myArray as $item) {
        if ($item[0] > $tmp[0] && ($item[0] < $lessthan || $lessthan === null)) {
            $tmp = $item;
        }
    }
    if ($tmp[0] < $lessthan || $lessthan === null) {
        $greaters[] = $tmp;
        $nbrItems++;
        $lessthan = $tmp[0];
    }
}
print_r($greaters);
```

It's always interesting to do not use existing functions and see how we can make it work... :)